# Verificar se URL no formato correto

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-amigável

Preciso é verificar se a url está no formato certo, e se ela não estiver, redirecionar para a url certa.

Em outra `Controller` já tem um código que faz isso que preciso, só preciso adaptar ele para outra `Controller`, pois o formato da url é diferente.

**O código é este:**

```
// redirect to real list_route
if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->blog->url_format($post)) {
  redirect(base_url().$this->blog->url_format($post),'location','301');
  exit;
```

A função com que ele faz a comparação na Model é a seguinte:

```
public function url_format($post,$extra=FALSE) {
    $title = isset($post->post_title) ? $post->post_title : $post->title;
    $title = isset($post->url) ? $post->url : $title;
    return $lang_domin.strtolower(url_title($title)).'-postid-'.$post->id.$extra;
}
```

Este código está funcionando perfeitamente. Mas a questão é que preciso fazer a comparação com esta função:

```
public function url_format_category($category,$extra=FALSE) {
    $title = json_decode($category->metadata)->{lang('blog_language')} != '' ? json_decode($category->metadata)->{lang('blog_language')} : $category->title;

    $preffix = trim($title) != '' ? '/'.strtolower(url_title($title)) : '';
    $preffix = trim($category->url) != '' ? '/'.strtolower(url_title($category->url)) : $preffix;
    return site_url(lang('list_route').'/'.$category->id.$preffix);
}
```

**Eu tentei fazer desta forma:**

```
public function post_list($category=FALSE,$category_name=FALSE) {
    if($category != FALSE) {
        $data['category_session'] = $this->blog->get_categories($category);
        $this->seo_tags->meta_title = (json_decode($data['category_session'][0]->metadata)->{lang('blog_language')} != '' ? json_decode($data['category_session'][0]->metadata)->{lang('blog_language')} : $data['category_session'][0]->title).' - '.$this->seo_tags->meta_title;

        if($this->uri_string != $this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0])) {
            redirect(base_url().$this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0]));
            exit;
        }
    }
```

**Porém a url retorna desta forma:**

> http://localhost/reweb/trunk/http://localhost/blog/trunk/novidades-e-estrategias-de-marketing-digital-em-nosso-blog/1/seo

E com este erro:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /blog/trunk/http://localhost/blog/trunk/novidades-e-estrategias-de-marketing-digital-em-nosso-blog/1/seo on this server.

Comment: Mil opções. Arquivos de configuração do servidor web (Nginx, Apache etc), configuração de rotas do Framework, configuração da rota específica para acessar o sistema-online... Se você colocar os códigos que tem acesso e que está criando, a gente tem como fazer sugestões. Eu, normalmente, uso as configurações de rotas e dos controladores, no Framework.

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro Eu utilizo o CodeIgniter. Tenho as rotas especificadas no arquivo Routes. E é exatamente isso que preciso fazer, pelas configurações da route e da  controller.

Comment: Acredito que o mais coerente é: caso a url tenha algum dado errado ou mesmo o parâmetro, que seja direcionada para o 404 da pagina na função `show_404();`

Ou redirecionar para uma rota padrão se não encontrar sua pagina (slug, cadastro) no banco de dados caso tenha em: `$routes['novidades/(:any)'] = 'blog/padrao';`

Comment: O que seu model em `$this->blog->url_format($post)` recebe como parâmetro e qual o formato da string retornada?

Comment: @GWER Por favor, edite a questão e adicione nela todas essas informações ao invés de deixar como comentários... depois apague os comentários. Essas informações fazem parte da questão.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta e inseri mais informações. @MiguelAngelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que `$this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0]));` já está te retornando a URL inteira.

Tente trocar:

> redirect(base_url().$this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0]));

por

> redirect($this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0]));

Ou seja, somente retirando o `base_url()`

Comment: Dando um die() em `this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0])`realmente me retornou a url inteira, retirei o `base_url()` mas agora a página não abre, da o seguinte erro no navegador : `A página da web em http://localhost/blog/trunk/novidades-e-estrategias-de-marketing-digital-em-nosso-blog/4/marketing-digital-imobilirio resultou em muitos redirecionamentos.`

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneira `if(base_url().$this->uri->uri_string != $this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0])) {
   redirect($this->blog->url_format_category($data['category_session'][0]), 'location', '301');
    exit;
   }`

Comment: Que bom que te ajudei a resolver essa parada rs Até estou baixando o CI de novo para pegar pratica nele novamente. Sou adepto do uso do var_dump() para ver os valores exatos que estão chegando, me salvam sempre...fica ai a dica =)

Comment: Valeu cara, me salvou! Estou iniciando na programação agora, um erro bem de iniciante mesmo. Hehe

Comment: Bom, esta no caminho certo, perguntando, tentando e fazendo =)

Comment: Valeu! Dentro de 5 horas já concedo os 50 pontos de gratificação (é o tempo que preciso esperar) :)

Comment: Sem problemas =)